# simpel Haskell list sorting/shuffling in a pattern

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make an algorithm that takes in a list and reorganizes the list according to the following operation steps.

```
[1 , 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9 ]
[1 , 3, 5 , 7, 9 ] ++ [2 , 4, 6, 8 ]
[1 , 3, 5 , 7, 9 ] ++ [2 , 6] ++ [ 4, 8 ]
[1 , 3, 5 , 7, 9 , 2, 6 , 4, 8 ]
```

This is I have come so far, then I do not know what I should do next. Any help?

```
ever xs = if xs == [] then [ ] else head xs: ever (drop 1 residue)
    Where residue 1 drop = xs
```

Comment: Just to be clear: are your steps separating the left-most list in a modulo2 way? (Odd-indexed elements to the left, even-indexed elements to the right)

Comment: not really, it's supposed to take every other element from the list. it should work for strings

Comment: What is "every other element"? And strings also have odd-indexed and even-indexed elements (in "abcd", "ac" is even-indexed and "bd" is odd-indexed).

Comment: it will skip every other index to later do the same with the ones you have skipped. it's more of an index elapse .
[ 3,5,7,9,11,13 , ]
   [ 3,7,11 ] ++ [ 5,9,13 ]
      [ 3,7,11 ] ++ [ 5,13 ] ++ [9 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a more combinatorial approach for better readability.

```
import Data.Either

alternate :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
alternate fs = zipWith ($) (cycle fs)

shuffle = (\es -> lefts es ++ rights es) . alternate [Left,Right]
```

`alternate` rotates the functions applied to a list. In `shuffle` the constructors for `Either` get applied alternately. Then we simply cut lefts and rights out of the list and put them together.

Comment: Your function doesn't work properly, e.g. `shuffle [1..10]` returns `[1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10]` instead of `[1,3,5,7,9,2,6,10,4,8]`.

Comment: @user3237465 . @Shanth suggested `shuffle [] = [] ; shuffle xs = (\es -> lefts es ++ shuffle (rights es) ) $ alternate [Left,Right] xs` which is the right way to go. I didn't wanted to make it too easy. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a CPS version:

```
shuffle [] = []
shuffle xs = shuffle' xs shuffle where
    shuffle' (x:y:xs) cont = x : shuffle' xs (cont . (y:))
    shuffle'      xs  cont = xs ++ cont []
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
splitAlt :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitAlt = foldr (\x (ys, zs) -> (x:zs, ys)) ([],[])
```

The `splitAlt` function splits `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` into `([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8])`.

```
shuffle :: [a] -> [a]
shuffle [] = []
shuffle xs = let (ys,zs) = splitAlt xs
             in ys ++ shuffle zs
```

That should give you the result that you desire.

Comment: thanks I have not quite grasped splitAt module , and what it does in each recursion, thanks for the help